# Why html select is overlaying the container with overflow scroll?

Tags: html, css, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Please consider following sample html fragment:

```
<div id="panel-container">
    <div id="panel"style="overflow: scroll; height: 80px">
       <!-- some form fields -->
       <lightning-combobox />
       <select>
           <option>Some Option1</option>
           <option>Some Option2</option>
           <option>Some Option3</option>
           <option>Some Option4</option>
           <option>Some Option5</option>
       </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, when I expand custom combobox (salesforce ligthtning-combobox), the options to select are triggering the scroll to expand and not overlaying the whole panel.
But when I expand the standard html "select", it overlays correctly, all options are visible and scroll is not expanding. 
How does it work and how can I achieve similar behaviour in custom combobox?
I have a case when I want to have a scrollable panel with many form fields, but expanding combobox shouldn't cause the scroll to expand. It should overlay the panel.

Comment: `position: fixed` or `position: absolute` will not trigger scroll - will not expand contents of container. Show sample code of your `ComboboxFromExternalLibrary` to tell something more concrete

Comment: @Justinas Using such positioning would be inconvenient, because I would have to update the combobox position when user is scrolling (combo box would be positioned relatively to the "panel-container").
The custom combobox is just the lightning-combobox provided by Salesforce